# Populate the Phone Number field with the dialing code from the selected country

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'd like some help please.

I'm having a contact form build on Bootstrap and this is the part of my code I'd like to focus on

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country">* What country are you in ?</label>
    <select name="country" class="form-control"> // list of all countries here - comes from database
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="gre">Greece</option>
        <option value="ger">Gemany</option>
        <option value="fra">France</option>
        <option value="ita">Italy</option> 
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">* What’s your phone number ?</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is when I select a country from the dropdown to populate the phone field with the dialing code of the selected country. For example if I pick `United Kingdom` from the select menu then the phone field should have the +44 code at the beginning and then fill out my phone, So on the server side I should have something like this

```
$_POST['phone'] => +44 123456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well and you can add `data-attributes` to the `options` inside the `select`, you could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country">* What country are you in ?</label>
    <select name="country" class="form-control">// list of all countries here - comes from database
        <option data-code="+44" value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
        <option data-code="+30" value="gre">Greece</option>
        <option data-code="+49" value="ger">Gemany</option>
        <option data-code="+33" value="fra">France</option>
        <option data-code="+39" value="ita">Italy</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">* What’s your phone number ?</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[name='country']").on("change", function () {
        $("[name='phone']").val($(this).find("option:selected").data("code"));
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uzLwfbbh/)**

Comment: This seems to work and looks like with what I want to do .. but then if I submit the phone number and hit submit I'll still get the full phone number (i.e +44123456) ??

Comment: It should take the entire value inside the text input field, so including the country codes yes.

Answer (score 0):

use this html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="country">* What country are you in ?</label>
<select name="country" class="form-control"> // list of all countries here
    <option value="uk" code="44">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="gre" code="1">Greece</option>
    <option value="ger" code="2">Gemany</option>
    <option value="fra" code="3">France</option>
    <option value="ita" code="4">Italy</option> 
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="phone">* What’s your phone number ?</label>
   <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

then simply use jquery to add code to input field

```
$("select[name='country']").change(function(){
     $("input[name='country']").val("+"+ $('option:selected', this).attr('code'););
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just a need a javascript function 
as i did the following fiddler, no jquery required

https://jsfiddle.net/NWbsj/62/

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="country">* What country are you in ?</label>
    <select name="country" id="country" onchange="selectCountryCode();" class="form-control"> 
        <option value="11">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="12">Greece</option>
        <option value="13">Gemany</option>
        <option value="14">France</option>
        <option value="15">Italy</option> 
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">* What’s your phone number ?</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="form-control" />
</div>


function selectCountryCode(){
  var mySelect   = document.getElementById("country");
  var myInput    = document.getElementById("phone");

  myInput.value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value;


}
```